# Find first character that is different between two strings

Tags: php, string

Given two equal-length strings, is there an elegant way to get the offset of the first different character?

The obvious solution would be:

```
for ($offset = 0; $offset < $length; ++$offset) {
    if ($str1[$offset] !== $str2[$offset]) {
        return $offset;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't look quite right, for such a simple task.

Comment: Related: [Tetris'ing an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3275258)

Comment: Looks simple enough to me.

Comment: There are more efficient ways to do this, but possibly more complicated to read. Will this bit of code be called lots of times? I.e. Does it matter if it's efficient?

Comment: @Robert: How could it be done more efficiently? This is `O(n)` and you _will_ have to examine up to `n` characters.

Comment: @Tomalak You're right that it's O(n), but a byte-wise compare written in PHP will be much slower than a built-in function that utilizes C. For example, code strcmp in PHP and use built-in, run each 10000 times for a decently long string, and see how badly it loses.

Comment: !BE AWARE!, that this might result in a wrong offset when dealing with unicode characters. If you want doing it this way, better use [mb_substr()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can use a nice property of [bitwise XOR (`^`)](http://php.net/operators.bitwise) to achieve this:  Basically, when you xor two strings together, the characters that are the same will become null bytes (`"\0"`).  So if we xor the two strings, we just need to find the position of the first non-null byte using [`strspn`](http://php.net/strspn):

```
$position = strspn($string1 ^ $string2, "\0");
```

That's all there is to it.  So let's look at an example:

```
$string1 = 'foobarbaz';
$string2 = 'foobarbiz';
$pos = strspn($string1 ^ $string2, "\0");

printf(
    'First difference at position %d: "%s" vs "%s"',
    $pos, $string1[$pos], $string2[$pos]
);
```

That will output:

> First difference at position 7: "a" vs "i"

So that should do it.  It's **very** efficient since it's only using C functions, and requires only a single copy of memory of the string.

### Edit: A MultiByte Solution Along The Same Lines:

```
function getCharacterOffsetOfDifference($str1, $str2, $encoding = 'UTF-8') {
    return mb_strlen(
        mb_strcut(
            $str1,
            0, strspn($str1 ^ $str2, "\0"),
            $encoding
        ),
        $encoding
    );
}
```

First the difference at the byte level is found using the above method and then the offset is mapped to the character level. This is done using the [`mb_strcut`](http://php.net/mb_strcut) function, which is basically `substr` but honoring multibyte character boundaries.

```
var_dump(getCharacterOffsetOfDifference('foo', 'foa')); // 2
var_dump(getCharacterOffsetOfDifference('©oo', 'foa')); // 0
var_dump(getCharacterOffsetOfDifference('f©o', 'fªa')); // 1
```

It's not as elegant as the first solution, but it's still a one-liner (and if you use the default encoding a little bit simpler):

```
return mb_strlen(mb_strcut($str1, 0, strspn($str1 ^ $str2, "\0")));
```

Comment: Are you a ringer? How did NikiC _know_ you were planning on posting this?

Comment: @Robert Martin, visit our courses of telepathy [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).

Comment: @Robert: Yes, I am.  We had discussed this yesterday and Nikic had asked me to post this solution here now to give a baseline to see if there are any other (potentially better) solutions than this one.  And to get other's comments on it as well...

Comment: Out of curiosity,  why the downvote?  Is there something that can be improved or expanded upon (and as such perhaps should be discussed)?

Comment: I guess it is related to the difference in upvotes on comment #1 and comment #2 (unfortunately).

Comment: @jk I assume as much.  But if the answer could be improved, that is much more important than 2 measly rep points...

Comment: Very Clever code! BTW I notice there always seem to be random down votes when a bounty is involved. Been stung myself.

Comment: Nice. But the downside of this code is that it doesn't work with multibyte strings.

Comment: @Karolis: Correct.  It will find the byte offset of the difference though (which could be in the middle of a multi-byte character)...

Comment: +1 The XOR idea is brilliant.  I'll have to remember that in the future.  I've always used the method OP posted.

Comment: Doesn't [strcspn](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcspn.php) do this out of the box?

Comment: @Lance: nope.  `strcspn('abcd', 'abcd') === 0` ([on codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qEzUiE)), which is obviously not the same answer to this question (which in this case would be `4`)...  So no, it doesn't do that out of the box...

Comment: @ircmaxell can you start peer reviewing my tickets?

Comment: How do you find all characters diffrent with this approach

Comment: @Baba you save the XOR first and wrap `strspn()` in a loop and use it with the `$start` parameter

Answer (score 16):

If you convert a string to an array of single character one byte values you can use the array comparison functions to compare the strings.

You can achieve a similar result to the XOR method with the following.

```
$string1 = 'foobarbaz';
$string2 = 'foobarbiz';

$array1 = str_split($string1);
$array2 = str_split($string2);

$result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);

$num_diff = count($result);
$first_diff = key($result);

echo "There are " . $num_diff . " differences between the two strings. <br />";
echo "The first difference between the strings is at position " . $first_diff . ". (Zero Index) '$string1[$first_diff]' vs '$string2[$first_diff]'.";
```

#### Edit: Multibyte Solution

```
$string1 = 'foorbarbaz';
$string2 = 'foobarbiz';

$array1 = preg_split('((.))u', $string1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
$array2 = preg_split('((.))u', $string2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$result = array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);

$num_diff = count($result);
$first_diff = key($result);

echo "There are " . $num_diff . " differences between the two strings.\n";
echo "The first difference between the strings is at position " . $first_diff . ". (Zero Index) '$string1[$first_diff]' vs '$string2[$first_diff]'.\n";
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with working with multibyte encoding.  If someone could give more insight as to how this would hold up/how str_split works with mb it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It won't work with multibyte encodings.  If you wanted that, you'd pretty much have to use something like this:  `$array = preg_split('((.))u', $string, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`  Basically, it will split into individual UTF-8 characters...

Comment: Thanks for the `preg_split` tip, added it to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to add this as as comment to the best answer, but I do not have enough points.

```
$string1 = 'foobarbaz';
$string2 = 'foobarbiz';
$pos = strspn($string1 ^ $string2, "\0");

if ($pos < min(strlen($string1), strlen($string2)){
    printf(
        'First difference at position %d: "%s" vs "%s"',
        $pos, $string1[$pos], $string2[$pos]
    );
} else if ($pos < strlen($string1)) {
    print 'String1 continues with' . substr($string1, $pos);
} else if ($pos < strlen($string2)) {
    print 'String2 continues with' . substr($string2, $pos);
} else {
    print 'String1 and String2 are equal';
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
string strpbrk ( string $haystack , string $char_list )
```

strpbrk() searches the haystack string for a char_list.

The return value is the substring of $haystack which begins at the first matched character.
As an API function it should be zippy. Then loop through once, looking for offset zero of the returned string to obtain your offset.

Comment: What about when you have a string "foobarr" being compared to a string "foobaar".  There is no difference in character set, just the counts and positioning.

Comment: Not applicable here.  For example, if haystack is `abcdef` and char_list is `fedcba` it would return the entire string (since `a` is in the char list).  So while this function would work for a very limited subset of possible inputs, it won't work in a generic way, so it's not a good answer to the question.

Comment: @NikiC asked for "an elegant way to get the offset of the first different character". The first character in your example is the correct answer, ircmaxell. While Steve has a better point. I love the  xor approach, however unicode is the fly in that ointment. Hmmmm....

Comment: @Sinthia: correct, however it would also return `abcdef` when the char_list is `abcdef` as well.  So it's only "accidental" that it returns the correct answer.