# match two strings and compare each letter in php

Tags: php

I googled this question I can't to find the exact solution...

I have 2 variables...

```
$s1 = "ABC"; //or "BC"
$s2 = "BC"; //or "Bangalore"
```

I have to compare `$s1` and `$s2` and give the output as `letters which is not present in $s2`
`eg : "A" // or"C"`

Like that 
I have to compare `$s2` and `$s1` and give the output as `letters which is not present in $s1`
`eg : null // or"angalore"`

What I tried..
I spit the strings to array...
Using nested for loop to find the non matched letters...
I wrote code more than 35 lines..
But no result :(
Please help me ......

Comment: Do you really want to compare single letters? In the example you give the result could never be "Angalore", because it would only return single letters.

Comment: let's say ... "ABC" and "Bangalore" are Sets (Set theory of Math), then you want "ABC" minus "Bangalore" and "Bangalore" minus "ABC". is it what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475437/find-first-character-that-is-different-between-two-strings

Comment: `$s1 = "ABC";` or `$s1 = "BC"` just i gave two value for example.... please take any one `$s1 = "ABC";` `$s2 = "BC";` or `$s1 = "BC";` `$s2 = "Bangalore";`

Comment: @Rotherford I already saw that post.. that is different

Answer (score 3):

```
echo str_ireplace(str_split($s2), "", $s1); // output: A
```

Comment: Dont know why this was down-voted - simplest and most concise answer!

Comment: haha I am commenting saying why the down-vote - it was me! I must have slipped - like I said best answer

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_diff()`](https://www.php.net/array_diff) here:

```
function str_compare($str1, $str2)
{
    $str1chars = str_split($str1);
    $str2chars = str_split($str2);
    $diff = array_diff($str1chars, $str2chars)
    return implode($diff);
}
```

By calling the function as follows:

```
$diffchars = str_compare('ABC', 'BC');
```

You will receive a string containing the characters  that do not appear in both strings. In this example, it'll be `A`, because that character appears in `$str1`, but not in `$str2`.

Comment: Wow, your `for` loop for creating the array of characters quickly changed to `str_split()` ;)

Comment: @AmalMurali indeed it did. One of those moments where I completely forgot about `str_split()`!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff):

```
function str_diff($str1, $str2) {
    $arr1 = str_split($str1);
    $arr2 = str_split($str2);
    $diff = array_diff($arr1, $arr2);
    return implode($diff);
}
```

Usage:

```
echo str_diff('BC', 'Bangalore'); // => C
echo str_diff('ABC', 'BC');       // => A
```

Comment: @TunZarniKyaw he had the return values reversed. Updated.

Comment: oops, i didn't downvote, just wanted to point out what is incorrect in comment

Answer (score 2):

You can use [str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) and [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) like :

```
<?php
$s1 = 'abcedf';
$s2 = 'xzcedf5460gf';

print_r(array_diff(str_split($s1), str_split($s2)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok to do this

```
$str1s = "abc";
$str2s = "BCd";


function findNot($str1, $str2, $asArray = false){

    $returnValue = array_diff(array_unique(str_split(strtolower($str1))), array_unique(str_split(strtolower($str2))));

    if($asArray == false){

        return implode($returnValue);

    }else{

        return $returnValue;

    }

}

echo findNot($str1s, $str2s); //gives a string
echo findNot($str1s, $str2s, true); //gives array of characters
```

This allows you to return as either array or string.