# i want to compare the string and show to characters which match in both strings in php

Tags: php

i want to compare the string and show to characters which match in both strings in php i tried everything but failed to do this please give me any idea how to do this in php
e.g i have two variables

I have to compare $a and $b and give the output as letters whicj are common in both

```
$a="hello ";
$b= "hell";
```

output should be :  :: hell as first 4 character matches so it should show hell please help me to do this

i have tried everything almost everything which i know or could i find on web
 What I tried.. I spit the strings to array... Using nested for loop to find the non matched letters... I wrote code more than 35 lines.. But no result :( Please help me ......

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should at least provide a sample of the different approaches you are using.

Comment: please make your question clear, is word and  drow have the same 'w', 'o', 'r', 'd'.

Comment: this is an (exact) copy of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921590/match-two-strings-and-compare-each-letter-in-php?rq=1

Comment: It would have helped to see those 35 lines of code. Your question is not too clear. What happens to strings like 'color' and 'colour' should the result just be 'colo' or should it be 'color'? What if the same letters are there but in different order. What is the scenario you are using? Compare correct amswers? Be more specific and you will get a perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it would be enough to use `array_intersect` and `str_split` functions to get characters common to both input strings(of course, if order of characters doesn't matter):

```
$a = "hello ";
$b = "hell";
$common = array_intersect(str_split(trim($a)), str_split(trim($b)));

print_r($common);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => h
    [1] => e
    [2] => l
    [3] => l
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: array_intersect() is good.Please add reference link so reader can view in depth.

Comment: @VasimVanzara, added reference link

Answer (score 0):

This PHP code is the one you need.

```
<?php


$a = "hello";
$b = "hell";

$str = "";

for ($i=0; $i < strlen($a); $i++) { 
    for ($j=0; $j < strlen($b); $j++) { 
        if ($a[$i]==$b[$j]) {
            $str.=$a[$i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
echo $str;

?>
```

PHP Strings can be seen as Char arrays so $a[0] get you the first char of the string.

Comment: Apart from whether or not this code will do the job you make a very often made mistake. Do not use the function to determine stringlength (in any language) in the `for` command. The length is not going to change and yet you are calculating it over and over. Put the value in a variable before the `for` command.

Comment: Yep that's right. It's better calculating the length before.