# Sorting 2d array by column with inconsistent format

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, custom-sort

My array is like so:

```
[
    ['name' => 'abc-def-12', 'qty' => 250, 'sub_qty' => '1385', 'Location' => 'NOP01'],    
    ['name' => 'abc-def-23', 'qty' => 1234, 'sub_qty' => '615, 101, 432, 116', 'Location' => 'NOP10, NOP04, NOP08, NOP06'],
    ['name' => 'abc-def-34', 'qty' => 379, 'sub_qty' => 62, 'Location' => 'NOP08'],
    ['name' => 'abc-def-45', 'qty' => 425, 'sub_qty' => '372, 89', 'Location' => 'NOP07, NOP05'],    
    ['name' => 'abc-def-56', 'qty' => 0],
    ['name' => 'abc-def3.FMF', 'qty' => 523, 'sub_qty' => '240, 103, 180', 'Location' => 'NOP06, NOP08, NOP11'],
]
```

I'm having issues sorting the array where `abc-def3.FMF` comes before `abc-def-12`. This is after I've sorted the array using:

```
function sortNames($a, $b){
  return strcmp ($a['name'], $b['name']);
}
```

which prevent the names from lining up like so: `abc-def-12, abc-def-23, abc-def3.FMF, abc-def-34, abc-def-45, abc-def-56`

How might I achieve my goal so the array prints like:

```
[
    ['name' => 'abc-def3.FMF', 'qty' => 523, 'sub_qty' => '240, 103, 180', 'Location' => 'NOP06, NOP08, NOP11'],
    ['name' => 'abc-def-12', 'qty' => 250, 'sub_qty' => '1385', 'Location' => 'NOP01'],    
    ['name' => 'abc-def-23', 'qty' => 1234, 'sub_qty' => '615, 101, 432, 116', 'Location' => 'NOP10, NOP04, NOP08, NOP06'],
    ['name' => 'abc-def-34', 'qty' => 379, 'sub_qty' => 62, 'Location' => 'NOP08'],
    ['name' => 'abc-def-45', 'qty' => 425, 'sub_qty' => '372, 89', 'Location' => 'NOP07, NOP05'],    
    ['name' => 'abc-def-56', 'qty' => 0],
]
```

Comment: Do all the items start with abc-def-?

Comment: You should add more logic to your `sortNames()` function so that it knows how to order the results the way you want them.

Comment: @alanfcm abc-def as you see it has been chunked from a much larger array where the starting characters are different; only the first 7 characters will connect the items in the array to be chunked.

Comment: There's no built-in comparison function that will make `abc-def3.FMF` come before `acb-def-12`, you'll have to write a custom function that implements whatever your logic is.

Comment: It's not obvious from that one example what all the rules of your comparison logic are.

Comment: @Barmar understood. The simplest form of the logic is that all items pattern matching `xxx-xxx#` must come before items matching `xxx-xxx-#`, with the second dash being the key difference.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475437/find-first-character-that-is-different-between-two-strings?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa for how to find the first different character. Then you can check if one of them is a number and the other is `-`, and order them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Because [`version_compare()` replaces hyphens with dots](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php), it appears to be adequate for sorting your provided sample data.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DUjNa))

```
usort($array, fn($a, $b) => version_compare($a['name'], $b['name']));
var_export($array);
```